# Facebook Login doesn't work when I use Samsung Android 4.2

Tags: android, facebook

When I use HTC Android, it do very well. However, when I use API of Facebook to login using Samsung Android 4.2, I show an Toast message like "login fail please contact the marker of this app and ask them to issue 1732910 to facebook"

Please help me to fix it!

```
public class FacebookLogin {
/* variable Facebook */
private static final String FACEBOOK_APPID = "578073962236765";
private FacebookConnector facebookConnector;
private final Handler mFacebookHandler = new Handler();
ActivityBase activity;
Request.GraphUserCallback userCallback;
LoginService.OnSwimLogedInEvents swimLoginCallBack;
LoginService loginService;
Dialog changeDialog;
LoadingDialog loadingDialog;

public FacebookLogin(ActivityBase activity, Request.GraphUserCallback userCallback, LoginService.OnSwimLogedInEvents swimLoginCallBack) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog();
    this.userCallback = userCallback;
    this.swimLoginCallBack = swimLoginCallBack;
    this.loginService = new LoginService(activity);
    this.facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(FACEBOOK_APPID,
            activity, activity, new String[]{
            "publish_stream", "email", "user_birthday", "read_stream", "offline_access"});
}

public void login() {
    Session.initializeStaticContext(activity);
    if (facebookConnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid()) {
        facebookConnector.getFacebook().getSession()
                .closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

    AuthListener listener = new AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            doLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
            //(new MessageAlert()).showDialog("Facebook authetication fail\r\nError:" + error, activity);
        }
    };
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);

    facebookConnector.login();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    facebookConnector.getFacebook().authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void doLogin() {
    AsyncTaskBase<Void, Void, Void> t = new AsyncTaskBase<Void, Void, Void>(
            activity) {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mFacebookHandler.post(facebookUserInfoRunner);
            return super.doInBackground(params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    };
    t.execute();
}

final Runnable facebookUserInfoRunner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       loadingDialog.showDialogLoading(activity);
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(facebookConnector.getFacebook()
                .getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                SwimAccount currentAccount = ((SwimApp) activity.getApplication()).getCurrentAccount();
                currentAccount.setAvatarUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture");
                currentAccount.setIsLogin(true);
                currentAccount.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
                currentAccount.setLastName(user.getLastName());
                currentAccount.setStringId(user.getId());
                currentAccount.setAccountType("facebook");
                currentAccount.setEmail((String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email"));
                currentAccount.setBirthdate(user.getBirthday());
                currentAccount.setGender((String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("gender"));
                if (userCallback != null) {
                    userCallback.onCompleted(user, response);
                }

                loginService.login(currentAccount.getEmail(), "", currentAccount.getAccountType(), currentAccount.getStringId(), swimLoginCallBack);
                //changeDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}

Comment: same here Please answer.

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm encountering the same problem with a Samsung S4 with 4.2+.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of facebook sdk. You can get it from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) and also go through the basic tutorials there.

Comment: I did and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: can you please show your Android Manifest? have you set this: android:launchMode="singleInstance"
in your manifest? what is the os version of your HTC? device model? or this can be the issue:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=43200939

Comment: Found this on the facebook developer site: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/400499173399130, since its already marked as closed, I suggest you create another one with better repo steps.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to my problem. Try deleting the `android:noHistory="true"` from the Facebook login activity in your manifest. This messes with the authentication flow of the Session.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like people on XDA have had this same problem.

They are claiming that you can try either of these:

(1) "Don't keep activities" option on Settings > Developer Options. If it's ON, then when an app calls some popup, system closes app, so then system restarts it ... and there got your loop.

(2) If you uninstall the Facebook App, you can then login through your app, and then re-install the Facebook app.

Not sure how "official" these answers are, but thought it might be worth a shot to you.

Sources: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=43200939 and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2186035

Comment: Tried them and they didn't help. I posted my solution (which fixed my problem), but I'm not sure if it will the other people's problems.