# New Facebook App causing issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have used `Facebook SDK` in my android app and try to login via facebook.

A problem comes at the user side, If the Facebook app is not installed on the device, the login succeeds, but if the device has the facebook app installed, then the login show the popup:

```
Login failed. please contact the maker of this app and ask them to report the issue 1732910 to Facebook.
```

I know there are certain posts on this issue, but I didn't find any solution.

Please help!

Comment: This link may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311451/facebook-login-doesnt-work-when-i-use-samsung-android-4-2

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that the activity in which is your Facebook is implemented doesn't have the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest file.